# How can I check if a specific user has specific access rights on a folder/file in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to write a function which tells me if a **specific user** has a specific rights on a folder. So far I have found an example on how to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637%28VS.85%29.aspx) so I tried to write this code in delphi.

```
unit SysCommonUnit;

interface

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  System.Math,
  Winapi.Windows,
  WinTypes;

const
  NERR_SUCCESS                     = 0;
  MAX_NR_USERS                     = 1000;
  FILTER_TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT    = $0001;
  FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT            = $0002;
  FILTER_PROXY_ACCOUNT             = $0004;
  FILTER_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT = $0008;
  FILTER_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT = $0010;
  FILTER_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT      = $0020;

  AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT    = $1;
  {$EXTERNALSYM AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT}

  FILE_READ_DATA            = $0001; // file & pipe
  FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY       = $0001; // directory
  FILE_WRITE_DATA           = $0002; // file & pipe
  FILE_ADD_FILE             = $0002; // directory
  FILE_APPEND_DATA          = $0004; // file
  FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY     = $0004; // directory
  FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE = $0004; // named pipe
  FILE_READ_EA              = $0008; // file & directory
  FILE_WRITE_EA             = $0010; // file & directory
  FILE_EXECUTE              = $0020; // file
  FILE_TRAVERSE             = $0020; // directory
  FILE_DELETE_CHILD         = $0040; // directory
  FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES      = $0080; // all
  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES     = $0100; // all

  FILE_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED or
                    SYNCHRONIZE or
                    $1FF;

  FILE_GENERIC_READ = STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ or
                      FILE_READ_DATA or
                      FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or
                      FILE_READ_EA or
                      SYNCHRONIZE;

  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE =  STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE or
                        FILE_WRITE_DATA or
                        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES or
                        FILE_WRITE_EA or
                        FILE_APPEND_DATA or
                        SYNCHRONIZE;

  FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE =  STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE or
                          FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or
                          FILE_EXECUTE or
                          SYNCHRONIZE;

type
  ACE_HEADER = record
    AceType: BYTE;
    AceFlags: BYTE;
    AceSize: WORD;
  end;

  PPSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR = ^PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;

  PACE_HEADER = ^ACE_HEADER;

  PAUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST = ^AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;

  POBJECT_TYPE_LIST = ^OBJECT_TYPE_LIST;

  _OBJECT_TYPE_LIST = record
    Level: WORD;
    Sbz: WORD;
    ObjectType: PGUID;
  end;

  OBJECT_TYPE_LIST = _OBJECT_TYPE_LIST;

  TObjectTypeList = OBJECT_TYPE_LIST;
  PObjectTypeList = POBJECT_TYPE_LIST;

  _AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST = record
    DesiredAccess: ACCESS_MASK;
    PrincipalSelfSid: PSID;
    ObjectTypeList: POBJECT_TYPE_LIST;
    ObjectTypeListLength: DWORD;
    OptionalArguments: PVOID;
  end;

  AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST = _AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;

  TAuthzAccessRequest = AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;
  PAuthzAccessRequest = PAUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;

  PAUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY = ^AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;

  _AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY = record
    ResultListLength: DWORD;
    GrantedAccessMask: PACCESS_MASK;
    SaclEvaluationResults: PDWORD;
    Error: PDWORD;
  end;

  AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY = _AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;

  TAuthzAccessReply = AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;
  PAuthzAccessReply = PAUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;

  TCHAR = char;

  AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE = THANDLE;

  AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE = THANDLE;

  AUTHZ_AUDIT_EVENT_HANDLE = THANDLE;

  PAUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE = ^AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;

  PAUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE = ^AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;

  PFN_AUTHZ_DYNAMIC_ACCESS_CHECK = function(hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
                                            pAce: PACE_HEADER;
                                            pArgs: PVOID;
                                            var pbAceApplicable: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;

  PFnAuthzDynamicAccessCheck = PFN_AUTHZ_DYNAMIC_ACCESS_CHECK;

  PFN_AUTHZ_COMPUTE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS = function(hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
                                              Args: PVOID;
                                              var pSidAttrArray: PSIDAndAttributes;
                                              var pSidCount: DWORD;
                                              var pRestrictedSidAttrArray: PSIDAndAttributes;
                                              var pRestrictedSidCount: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

  PFnAuthzComputeDynamicGroups = PFN_AUTHZ_COMPUTE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;

  PFN_AUTHZ_FREE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS = procedure(pSidAttrArray: PSIDAndAttributes); stdcall;

  PFnAuthzFreeDynamicGroups = PFN_AUTHZ_FREE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;

  AUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE = THANDLE;

  PAUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE = ^AUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE;


  SE_OBJECT_TYPE = (SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE,
                    SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                    SE_SERVICE,
                    SE_PRINTER,
                    SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
                    SE_LMSHARE,
                    SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
                    SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
                    SE_DS_OBJECT,
                    SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
                    SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
                    SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT);


function GetNamedSecurityInfoW( pObjectName: PWideChar;
                                ObjectType: SE_OBJECT_TYPE;
                                SecurityInfo: SECURITY_INFORMATION;
                                var ppSidOwner: PSID;
                                var ppSidGroup: PSID;
                                var ppDacl: PACL;
                                var ppSacl: PACL;
                                var ppSecurityDescriptor: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR): DWORD; stdcall; external 'Advapi32.dll';

function AuthzInitializeResourceManagerWrapper( nFlags: DWORD;
                                                pfnDynamicAccessCheck: PFN_AUTHZ_DYNAMIC_ACCESS_CHECK;
                                                pfnComputeDynamicGroups: PFN_AUTHZ_COMPUTE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;
                                                pfnFreeDynamicGroups: PFN_AUTHZ_FREE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;
                                                szResourceManagerName: string;
                                                var hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE): Boolean;

function AuthzInitializeContextFromSidWrapper(Flags: DWORD;
                                              UserSid: PSID;
                                              hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
                                              pExpirationTime: PLargeInteger;
                                              Identifier: LUID;
                                              DynamicGroupArgs: PVOID;
                                              var hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE): Boolean;

function AuthzFreeResourceManagerWrapper(hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE): Boolean;

function AuthzFreeContextWrapper(hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE): Boolean;

function AuthzAccessCheckWrapper( Flags: DWORD;
                                  hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
                                  var pRequest: AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;
                                  hAuditEvent: AUTHZ_AUDIT_EVENT_HANDLE;
                                  var pSecurityDescriptor: SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                                  var OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                                  OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount: DWORD;
                                  var pReply: AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;
                                  var phAccessCheckResultsOPTIONAL: AUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE): Boolean;

function ConvertUsernameToBinarySID(p_pAccountName: string): PSID;

function HasRightsForUser(p_hManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
                          p_oPsd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                          p_sUsername: string;
                          p_nDesiredRights: DWORD): Boolean;

function HasAccess(p_hAuthzClient: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE; p_oPsd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR; p_nDesiredRights: DWORD): Boolean;

function HasAccessRights(p_nDesiredRights: Integer; p_sFileName: string; p_sUsername: string): Boolean;

implementation

function AuthzInitializeResourceManagerWrapper( nFlags: DWORD;
                                                pfnDynamicAccessCheck: PFN_AUTHZ_DYNAMIC_ACCESS_CHECK;
                                                pfnComputeDynamicGroups: PFN_AUTHZ_COMPUTE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;
                                                pfnFreeDynamicGroups: PFN_AUTHZ_FREE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;
                                                szResourceManagerName: string;
                                                var hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE): Boolean;
var
  DLLHandle                       : THandle;
  wResourceManagerName            : array[0..1024] of Widechar;
  AuthzInitializeResourceManager  : function (nFlags: DWORD;
                                              pfnDynamicAccessCheck: PFN_AUTHZ_DYNAMIC_ACCESS_CHECK;
                                              pfnComputeDynamicGroups: PFN_AUTHZ_COMPUTE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;
                                              pfnFreeDynamicGroups: PFN_AUTHZ_FREE_DYNAMIC_GROUPS;
                                              szResourceManagerName: PWideChar;
                                              phAuthzResourceManager: PAUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE): BOOL; cdecl stdcall;
begin
  Result    := False;
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('authz.dll');
  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    @AuthzInitializeResourceManager := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'AuthzInitializeResourceManager');

    StringToWideChar(szResourceManagerName, wResourceManagerName, sizeof(wResourceManagerName));

    Result := AuthzInitializeResourceManager( nFlags,
                                              pfnDynamicAccessCheck,
                                              pfnComputeDynamicGroups,
                                              pfnFreeDynamicGroups,
                                              wResourceManagerName,
                                              @hAuthzResourceManager);
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;

function AuthzInitializeContextFromSidWrapper(Flags: DWORD;
                                              UserSid: PSID;
                                              hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
                                              pExpirationTime: PLargeInteger;
                                              Identifier: LUID;
                                              DynamicGroupArgs: PVOID;
                                              var hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE): Boolean;
var
  DLLHandle                       : THandle;
  AuthzInitializeContextFromSid   : function (Flags: DWORD;
                                              UserSid: PSID;
                                              hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
                                              pExpirationTime: PLargeInteger;
                                              Identifier: LUID;
                                              DynamicGroupArgs: PVOID;
                                              hAuthzClientContext: PAUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE): BOOL; cdecl stdcall;
begin
  Result    := False;
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('authz.dll');

  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    @AuthzInitializeContextFromSid := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'AuthzInitializeContextFromSid');
    Result := AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(Flags,
                                            UserSid,
                                            hAuthzResourceManager,
                                            pExpirationTime,
                                            Identifier,
                                            DynamicGroupArgs,
                                            @hAuthzClientContext);
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;

function AuthzFreeResourceManagerWrapper(hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE): Boolean;
var
  DLLHandle                       : THandle;
  AuthzFreeResourceManager        : function(hAuthzResourceManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE): BOOL; cdecl stdcall;
begin
  Result    := False;
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('authz.dll');

  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    @AuthzFreeResourceManager := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'AuthzFreeResourceManager');
    Result := AuthzFreeResourceManager(hAuthzResourceManager);

    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;

function AuthzFreeContextWrapper(hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE): Boolean;
var
  DLLHandle               : THandle;
  AuthzFreeContext        : function(hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE): BOOL; cdecl stdcall;
begin
  Result    := False;
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('authz.dll');

  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    @AuthzFreeContext := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'AuthzFreeResourceManager');
    Result := AuthzFreeContext(hAuthzClientContext);

    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;


function AuthzAccessCheckWrapper( Flags: DWORD;
                                  hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
                                  var pRequest: AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;
                                  hAuditEvent: AUTHZ_AUDIT_EVENT_HANDLE;
                                  var pSecurityDescriptor: SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                                  var OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                                  OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount: DWORD;
                                  var pReply: AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;
                                  var phAccessCheckResultsOPTIONAL: AUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE): Boolean;
var
  nError                  : Integer;
  DLLHandle               : THandle;
  AuthzAccessCheck        : function( Flags: DWORD;
                                      hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
                                      pRequest: PAUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;
                                      hAuditEvent: AUTHZ_AUDIT_EVENT_HANDLE;
                                      pSecurityDescriptor: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ;
                                      OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray: PPSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                                      OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount: DWORD;
                                      pReply: PAUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;
                                      phAccessCheckResultsOPTIONAL: PAUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE): BOOL; cdecl stdcall;
begin
  Result    := False;
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('authz.dll');

  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    @AuthzAccessCheck := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'AuthzAccessCheck');
    Result := AuthzAccessCheck(Flags,
                               hAuthzClientContext,
                               @pRequest,
                               hAuditEvent,
                               @pSecurityDescriptor,
                               @OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray,
                               OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount,
                               @pReply,
                               @phAccessCheckResultsOPTIONAL);

    if not Result then
      nError := GetLastError;

    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;


function HasAccessRights(p_nDesiredRights: Integer; p_sFileName: string; p_sUsername: string): Boolean;
var
  nDW      : DWORD;
  pSidOwner: PSID;
  pSidGroup: PSID;
  pPsd     : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
  oDAcl    : PACL;
  oSAcl    : PACL;
  hManager : AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
  bRes     : Boolean;
begin
  oSAcl     := nil;
  oDAcl     := nil;
  pSidOwner := nil;
  pSidGroup := nil;
  pPsd      := nil;

  hManager  := 0;

  Result    := False;

  try
    nDW := GetNamedSecurityInfoW( PWideChar(p_sFileName),
                                  SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                                  DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION or OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                  pSidOwner,
                                  pSidGroup,
                                  oDAcl,
                                  oSAcl,
                                  pPsd);

    if nDW <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      Exit;

    bRes := AuthzInitializeResourceManagerWrapper(AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT, nil, nil, nil, PWideChar(EmptyStr), hManager);
    if not bRes then
      Exit;

    bRes := HasRightsForUser(hManager, pPsd, p_sUsername, p_nDesiredRights);
    if not bRes then
      Exit;

    Result := True;

  finally
    AuthzFreeResourceManagerWrapper(hManager);
    if Assigned(pPsd) then
      LocalFree(HLOCAL(pPsd));

  end;
end;

function HasRightsForUser(p_hManager: AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
                          p_oPsd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
                          p_sUsername: string;
                          p_nDesiredRights: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  hAuthzClientContext: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
  bResult            : Boolean;
  n_UnusedID         : LUID;
  oSid               : PSID;
begin
  hAuthzClientContext := 0;
  Result              := false;
  n_UnusedID.LowPart  := 0;
  n_UnusedID.HighPart := 0;

  oSid := ConvertUsernameToBinarySID(p_sUsername);

  if Assigned(oSid) then
  begin
    try
      bResult := AuthzInitializeContextFromSidWrapper(0, oSid, p_hManager, nil, n_UnusedID, nil, hAuthzClientContext);

      if not bResult then
        Exit;

      bResult := HasAccess(hAuthzClientContext, p_oPsd, p_nDesiredRights);

      if bResult then
        Result := True;

    finally
      if Assigned(oSid) then
        LocalFree(HLOCAL(oSid));

      AuthzFreeContextWrapper(hAuthzClientContext);
    end;
  end;
end;

function ConvertUsernameToBinarySID(p_pAccountName: string): PSID;
var
  psDomainName   : LPTSTR;
  nDomainNameSize: DWORD;
  oSid           : PSID;
  nSidSize       : DWORD;
  eSidType       : SID_NAME_USE;
  bResult        : Boolean;
begin
  Result          := nil;
  psDomainName    := nil;
  nDomainNameSize := 0;
  oSid            := nil;
  bResult         := false;

  try
    LookupAccountName(nil,             // lpServerName: look up on local system
      PWideChar(p_pAccountName), oSid, // buffer to receive name
      nSidSize, psDomainName, nDomainNameSize, eSidType);

    if GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
    begin
      oSid := LPTSTR(LocalAlloc(LPTR, nSidSize * SizeOf(TCHAR)));
      if not Assigned(oSid) then
        Exit;

      psDomainName := LPTSTR(LocalAlloc(LPTR, nDomainNameSize * SizeOf(TCHAR)));
      if not Assigned(psDomainName) then
        Exit;

      bResult := LookupAccountName( nil,  // lpServerName: look up on local system
                                    PWideChar(p_pAccountName),
                                    oSid, // buffer to receive name
                                    nSidSize,
                                    psDomainName,
                                    nDomainNameSize,
                                    eSidType);
      if bResult then
        Result := oSid;

    end
    else
      Exit;
  finally
    if Assigned(psDomainName) then
    begin
      LocalFree(HLOCAL(psDomainName));
    end;
    // Free pSid only if failed;
    // otherwise, the caller has to free it after use.
    if (bResult = false) and Assigned(oSid) then
    begin
      LocalFree(HLOCAL(oSid));
    end;
  end;
end;

function HasAccess(p_hAuthzClient: AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE; p_oPsd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR; p_nDesiredRights: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  oDescArray    : Pointer;
  oCheckResults : AUTHZ_ACCESS_CHECK_RESULTS_HANDLE;
  oAccessRequest: AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;
  oAccessReply  : AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;
  a_nBuffer     : array [0 .. 1024] of BYTE;
  bResult       : Boolean;
  oPsd          : SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
begin
  Result := False;

  //  Do AccessCheck.
  oAccessRequest.DesiredAccess        := FILE_TRAVERSE;
  oAccessRequest.PrincipalSelfSid     := nil;
  oAccessRequest.ObjectTypeList       := nil;
  oAccessRequest.OptionalArguments    := nil;
  oAccessRequest.ObjectTypeListLength := 0;

  ZeroMemory(@a_nBuffer, sizeof(a_nBuffer));

  oAccessReply.ResultListLength       := 1;
  oAccessReply.GrantedAccessMask      := PACCESS_MASK(@a_nBuffer);
  oAccessReply.Error                  := PDWORD(Cardinal(@a_nBuffer) + sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));

  oPsd    := SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR(p_oPsd^);
  bResult := AuthzAccessCheckWrapper( 0,
                                      p_hAuthzClient,
                                      oAccessRequest,
                                      0,
                                      oPsd,
                                      oDescArray,
                                      0,
                                      oAccessReply,
                                      oCheckResults);
  if bResult then
    Result := True;
end;

end.
```

My problem is on line 348 in AuthzAccessCheckWrapper

```
Result := AuthzAccessCheck(Flags,
                               hAuthzClientContext,
                               @pRequest,
                               hAuditEvent,
                               @pSecurityDescriptor,
                               @OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray,
                               OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount,
                               @pReply,
                               @phAccessCheckResultsOPTIONAL);

if not Result then
  nError := GetLastError;
```

Where I get the error 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)

I'm quite new to Delphi and this may be a beginner's error but I don't have any idea how to solve this so any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your `AuthzAccessCheckWrapper`, try changing `var pSecurityDescriptor: SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;` to `var pSecurityDescriptor: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;` and then in `HasAccess` get rid of the local variable `oPsd` and pass `p_oPsd` directly to the modified `AuthzAccessCheckWrapper`.

Comment: At some point it was that way, actually I forgot to revert this on my attempt to try different approaches. Same error anyway. Is there a way to find a more specific error than 'ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER', in this situation this error code doesn't help me very much

Comment: No, the api won't tell you more than that.   .. I don't think it would be easy for anyone to further assist on what parameter you might be having problem with, without knowing what parameters you are passing to the function.

Comment: From another module I just call HasAccessRights(FILE_GENERIC_READ, 'C:\Windows', 'Pavel'); where path is already validated and username is obtained from another function which list all users from system so input parameters are correct at this point, if something is wrong it's starts from this point.

Comment: Tried it, AuthzAccessCheck returned true. I later got an AV at AuthzFreeContext though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only write a **simple** function to retrieve the users permissions over a folder or file, you can try the WMI, in this case to get the security settings for a logical file or directory you can use the [`Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  WMI Class with the [GetSecurityDescriptor method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Check this sample code. This will check if a **particular user** had access in a folder (or file).

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Windows,
  Variants;

procedure  GetDirectoryAccess(const Path, UserName : string);
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  objSD         : OleVariant;
  LIndex        : Integer;
  LAccessMask   : DWORD;
  objAce        : OleVariant;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\cimv2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.Get(Format('Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting="%s"', [StringReplace(Path,'\','\\', [rfReplaceAll])]));
  if FWbemObjectSet.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)=0 then
  for LIndex:= VarArrayLowBound(objSD.DACL,1) to VarArrayHighBound(objSD.DACL,1) do
  if SameText(UserName, objSD.DACL[LIndex].Trustee.Name) then
  begin
     objAce:=objSD.DACL[LIndex];
     Writeln(Format('Trustee  Name     %s',[objAce.Trustee.Name]));
     Writeln(Format('Trustee  Domain   %s',[objAce.Trustee.Domain]));
     Writeln(Format('Ace Flags         %d',[Integer(objAce.AceFlags)]));
     Writeln(Format('Access Mask       %d',[Integer(objAce.AccessMask)]));

     LAccessMask:=objAce.AccessMask;
      if (LAccessMask and 1048576)=1048576 then
          Writeln('  Synchronize');
      if (LAccessMask and 524288 )=524288 then
          Writeln('  Write Owner');
      if (LAccessMask and 262144)=262144 Then
          Writeln('  Write ACL');
      if (LAccessMask and 131072)=131072 Then
          Writeln('  Read Security');
      if (LAccessMask and 65536)=65536 Then
          Writeln('  Delete');
      if (LAccessMask and 256)=256 Then
          Writeln('  Write Attributes');
      if (LAccessMask and 128)=128 Then
          Writeln('  Read Attributes');
      if (LAccessMask and 64)=64 Then
          Writeln('  Delete Dir');
      if (LAccessMask and 32)=32 Then
          Writeln('  Execute');
      if (LAccessMask and 16)=16 Then
          Writeln('  Write extended attributes');
      if (LAccessMask and 8)=8 Then
          Writeln('  Read   extended attributes');
      if (LAccessMask and 4)=4 Then
          Writeln('  Append');
      if (LAccessMask and 2)=2 Then
          Writeln('  Write');
      if (LAccessMask and 1)=1 Then
          Writeln('  Read');
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetDirectoryAccess('c:\lazarus','RRUZ');;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Note: Is nothing wrong with use the WinAPI too, but this sample shows how easy can be resolved this task using the WMI.

Comment: It seems very simple but I just tried this function and it doesn't seems to work properly (I mention that I'm using windows 8) and in my case `objSD.DACL[LIndex].Trustee.Name` will print name of the users group? It's something wrong on what I'm doing or this is the way it should work and I should check also if my user is in this group?

Comment: How I said on my answer this will check if a `particular user` has access to a resource (before that you must add the `user` to the security settings of the folder), if you want check the settings of a user that belongs to an `specific group` the code must be modified.